# Blue Underlined Text in React - text-decoration: none; (& Color) not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and am struggling to change the text color and remove the underline from the "links" on my nav bar.
Here's my code for my navbar:

```
 render() { return ( 
    <nav class='items'>

<ul>
<Navitem item="Home" tolink="/"  activec={this.activeitem}></Navitem>
<Navitem item="About" tolink="/about"  activec={this.activeitem}></Navitem>
<Navitem item="Education" tolink="/education"  activec={this.activeitem}></Navitem>
<Navitem item="Skills" tolink="/skills"  activec={this.activeitem}></Navitem>
<Navitem item="Contact" tolink="/contact"  activec={this.activeitem}></Navitem>
</ul>
    </nav>   
     )

}
```

and heres my CSS for the nav bar: (as you can see, I've tried changing the color and text decoration in several places to no avail. The blue underline and blue text still persists!

```
 nav
{

padding:60px 30px 0px 30px ;
flex:var(--sidebar-flex);
background-image: url('../src/Images/cb.gif');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
/*background: rgb(255, 255, 255);*/
/*background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%, rgba(132,124,252,1) 80%);*/
}

nav ul
{ 
  font-size:var(--fontsize-nav) ;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important; 
}
nav ul li
{ margin:60px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black !important; 
}

.Navitem
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

I'm still new to react so if this is a pretty simple fix I apologize! Thank you so much for any tips and if more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `text-decoration: none;` on the a tag rendered by the `NavLink` component. For example `nav ul li a {text-decoration: none}`

Answer (score 0):

Use text-decoration: none; on the `<a>` tag generated by your `NavItem` component.

for example

```
nav ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```